# How to automatically expand disk space as required on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

My team will build a website like Airbnb and we will need some kind of dedicated server on Amazon, but I want that server to be scalable automatically on the disk space.

For example, at the start of the project the website will have 100mb, I will have to pay for that 100mb disk space + the other server config
in the future when the space occupied will be 100 GB, I will have to pay for that 100gb space + the other server config. But I don't want to manually add disk space... I want it to be auto-scalable, or very very easy to increase the disk size.

A pay-as-you-go service will be perfect.

I don't want to buy a dedicated server from OVH and then when I need space to manually order a new disk drive and do all sorts of configs in the Linux server.

Do you know if there is a service like this on Amazon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking of "a server" does not match the capabilities offered by the cloud.

These days, it is best to **separate compute from database and storage**:

- Run your **compute** on Amazon EC2, or using containers or even serverless (AWS Lambda).
- Put your **database on Amazon RDS**, such as MySQL or even Amazon Aurora (which is MySQL-compatible and can auto-scale). It also takes care of backups, replication, etc.
- For **file storage** (outside of the database), use Amazon S3. For example, all of the **images** used to show homes can be served directly from S3. There is no limit to the amount of files you can store in S3. It can also handle per-user security using [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

This way, as your product matures, you can modify portions of the system (eg app) without impacting other parts. For example, you could scale across multiple servers, or move to serverless, without impacting the database or file storage systems.

Storage that is directly-attached to compute should be considered ephemeral (temporary) storage. This way, if a node fails, no data is lost. Use local storage for apps and temporary files, but not for persistent data storage. The result is that disk space really is not a consideration, since data is either stored in the database (which can auto-scale), or S3 (which has no storage limits).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Elastic File System: https://aws.amazon.com/efs/
or Elastic Block Storage: https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/

These are designed for the need you describe.  Compare other options at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-overview/storage-services.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question, because today there are many options to host a website. It depends on the technology you are using to develop it.
From my experience, I would suggest two options:

**Serverless**

Pay-as-you-go rings the bell of `Serverless` to me. You will pay proportionally to the amount of requests and computer processing. (https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/).
It is recommended for SPA (if you are developing frontend with **React**, **Vue**, **Angular** or something similar), your backend will be totally detached from it. You can further choose which language to program for each endpoint you will have available (using `lambda functions`).
You can host your `frontend` in **S3** (static files of the website) and create another **S3** to be used to store uploaded/dynamic files (images and so on).

It is totally auto-scalable from the very beginning. (no requests, no pricing, except the fee for file storage in **S3**, which is very fair)

**Elastic Beanstalk**

If you have a monolith (e.g: cakephp, ruby-on-rails, django, etc.), you can use the **Elastic Beanstalk** service (https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). You deploy it and set the auto-scaling criteria (e.g: latency, cpu, etc.)

**And how it applies to your question**: you want to share files between many computers assigned for the application by the auto-scaling. You can configure from the beginning to share a drive between them. This way you can handle common uploaded/dynamic/generated files easily (check this https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/4szgqm/elastic_beanstalk_with_a_shared_drive_efs_as_an/ and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html)

**Finally..**

For both cases, you will need to deal with your database server size, but AWS is providing some auto-scalling options for databases as well (**RDS** for SQL DBs). For **NoSQL** databases, there are also options for auto-scalling or just set the limits of read/write you want for the development phase and set a different one for production.

I'm sure I didn't covered all the options, you may be using something not listed above, but it covers most of the cases I have already worked with.

I hope it can help you!

Comment: I just realized that there is much to my question. We will develop the entire website in laravel with plain mysql. I don't think the problem will be at the mysql database size, but to the pictures of the ads uploaded. If it was just for a database I would have purchased a dedicated server with 100gb and it would be enough. I just need the scalable space for the images uploaded on the website. I need something similar to a dedicated server, i want to install my own apps. To summarize, a dedicated server with a chosen config ( proc, ram, etc ) except the hdd which i need to be auto-scalable

Comment: I get it. I would still sugest to use the elastic beanstalk (providing 1-N EC2s) and append an EFS to the instances, instead of proving a "dedicated" (which would be an EC2), that could need to be resized in the future. That's my personal opinion =)

Comment: But if you just want a single server, you can use EC2 and append to it an EFS. It fits well as an auto-scalable hdd (https://aws.amazon.com/efs/)